# Python terminal too short in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, printing

I have a very long 'print' of Aruba commands output that I created using Python in Visual Studio Code.

Is there a way to increase the output size in the Terminal so that more of the output commands can be seen?

Comment: how long is it? because you can scroll through the output console, so unless it's thousands of lines, you should be able to see it.

Comment: If it is very, very long maybe you can think of redirecting the output to the file instead?

Comment: @Mahrkeenrh It is 1,201 lines so far. Is there a setting I can change to have the console see more lines?

Comment: @trivvz Is there a python code that you know of that can output this to a file? maybe something that I could stick onto the end of this long code?

Comment: @sammysosa, you can do it when running the command from shell. In bash/powershell you can use `>` to redirect the standard output to the file. Eg. `python my_script.py > output.txt`

Comment: @sammysosa, you can do it also from Python itself if you prefer, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4675744/14458327)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this in the settings.json file:

```
"terminal.integrated.scrollback":1000;
```

The default value of it was 1000.